# Best way to dynamically call function

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For my project, I have `callable` objects (arbitrary NBT dict that is theoretically capable of calling an mcfunction) stored on an NBT array (the Stack).
At an arbitrary time in execution I want to be able to pop the callable off the Stack and somehow use it to call a function.

My original thought was to just store a string like `"function ns:fn_name"` and then `data modify...` that string into a command block and run it.
Problem is, command blocks execute on the next tick and there seems to be no way around this.

My next thought would be to have an `invoker` function that contains every possible function call, and a chain of `execute if data stack[0]{name:<function_name>} run function ns:<function_name>`, where `stack[0]` is the callable at the top of the stack, and the callable would store the name of its desired function in `callable.name`.

My problem with this is efficiency. For the number of defined functions n, it's potentially adding n checks every function call and that sucks.

However, I can't think of a better way to call an arbitrary function like this.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there is a good and performant way to run an arbitrary function in the same tick without hardcoding all options. If performance is your concern, there would be multiple ways to improve the check so you don't have to check the nbt against every possible function name: 1) map the function names to integers - that way you can get the number from the storage once and then do cheap scoreboard checks. 2) get the length of the function name, then only check the ones with the same length. 3) use a binary tree lookup table to cut down on required checks.